# Error in "class-wp-hook.php"

Tags: functions

I got this error, can someone help me with how to resolve it?

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid function name in C:\Users\Alex\Local Sites\proba2\app\public\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 292

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This means that you have a hook set up to call wp_schedule_https_detection but no actual definition of that function. If you have a recent enough WordPress, 5.7+, then it should be defined in wp-includes/https-detection.php which should be included from wp-settings.php. (And the add_action to set up the hook call in default-filters.php.) Can you check that's all set up correctly? If not it might be worth doing a manual WordPress core upgrade to replace all of your core files with a good version.

Comment: I just checked wp and it is up to date (5,7). But I don't know how to check all the functions that you said. Can you check those functions? I could send you  wp-settings.php, and other files that are needed.

Comment: I meant look for `function wp_schedule_https_detection() {` in wp-includes/https-detection.php (line 163 I think) and `require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/https-detection.php';` in wp-settings.php (line 174). But if it's easier then just compare those two files to the files in a fresh copy of 5.7.

Comment: I just checked and I found those two lines of code that you said.

Comment: OK, then you shouldn't be getting this warning any more.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I faced similar issue after php8.0 upgrade from php7.4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788729/uncaught-typeerror-call-user-func-array-argument-1-function-must-be-a-va

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue, by checking and removing the missing function from the plugin file, as the error mentions  "function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' not found or invalid function name"

Probably you are calling the function 'wp_schedule_https_detection' in your plugin file, and its missing the function in the plugin file.

The file 'class-wp-hook.php' should not be edited

Comment: This is core WordPress code though. You shouldn't be removing anything.